# Correct likelihood to model distribution with positive and negative values, and a large number of zeroes?

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian

I have a change score as my dependent variable, which appears to be highly kurtotic (the majority of people don't change, but a few participants change by a large degree).  I cannot figure out the distribution that best approximates this data (as determined by a posterior predictive check in the bayesplot package).

If a fit a gaussian (default) for example:

```
gauss <- stan_lmer(happiness_change ~ treatment + (1|team), 
                   data = df, algorithm = "meanfield") 

pp_check(gauss, nreps = 100) + xlab("frequency")
```

I get the following:

[image]

I cannot figure out which of the model families approximates this distribution.  Or, rather, what transformation makes sense for this case?

Comment: If you have a large point mass at zero, what about trying to model it as a mixture of two distributions? The Stan manual should have a detailed description regarding how to do so in the chapter on "finite mixtures".

Comment: What would the two distributions be?

Comment: It would depend on the nature of the data, I suppose. For example, are values concentrated at the "exact" value of zero? or are they concentrated "near" zero? If it is the latter case, you could try a mixture of normals, or if that does not work out maybe trying a t-distribution seems sensible. In the former case, you can have a model for the point mass at zero and another distribution to model the points away from zero. I've never modeled such data myself, so this is just intuition.